# Is it possible to populate spring util:list via properties file?

Tags: spring, properties, spring-el, spelevaluationexception

I would like to populate transport End points via properties file. I tried this but it didn't work

```
<util:properties id="cxfProperties" location="/WEB-INF/classes/cxf.properties" />

<util:list id="transportEndpoints">
    <!--
    <value>http://localhost:8080/doubleit/services/doubleit.*</value>
    -->
    <value>#{cxfProperties.service.wsdllocation}</value>
</util:list>
```

In my properties file I have

```
service.wsdllocation=http://localhost:8080/doubleit/services/doubleit.*
```

I get error:

> Expression parsing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
>   EL1008E:(pos 14): Field or property 'service' cannot be found on
>   object of type 'java.util.Properties'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think SpEL provides direct field access syntax for property in `Properties`.  So I think the correct syntax should be:

```
#{cxfProperties.getProperty('service.wsdllocation')}
```

or

```
#{cxfProperties.getProperty('service.wsdllocation', 'SOME_DEFAULT_VAL')}
```

Comment: I get following error with it:  Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 14): Field or property 'service' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.Properties'

Comment: are you sure that you are using the new expressions I gave? Because in my expressions, there is no navigation of field/property of `service` anymore, which contradicts to your error message.  You may have simply used your old expression.

Comment: Have just created a testing project, and my suggestion is working as expected.